# Como deixar o menu selecionado ativo com jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, menu

Gostaria de saber como fazer para deixar o menu selecionado ativo.

Segue como está meu código html e js, acredito que não está funcionando pois quando redireciona para o link da tag < a >, perde o js, quando eu uso preventDefault funciona como eu queria, porém não vai para o link do menu.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```js
 $('.item-menu').click(function (e)
 {
  $('.item-menu').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
 });
```

```html
 <ul class="menu-main">
  <li class="item-menu active"><a class="item-a" href="home.php?p=link">Link</a></li>
  <li class="item-menu"><a class="item-a" href="home.php?p=link1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li class="item-menu"><a class="item-a" href="home.php?p=link2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li class="item-menu"><a class="item-a" href="home.php?p=link3">Link 3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes fazer isso no PHP, adicionando a classe, ou fazer em JS verificando o `location.search` e procurando o link que lhe corresponde.

```js
$('.item-menu').click(function(e) {
  $('.item-menu').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});

// verificar via JS:
const href = [location.pathname, location.search].join('?');
$('.item-menu[href="' + href + '"]').addClass('active');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-main">
  <li class="item-menu active"><a class="item-a" href="home.php?p=link">Link</a></li>
  <li class="item-menu"><a class="item-a" href="home.php?p=link1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li class="item-menu"><a class="item-a" href="home.php?p=link2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li class="item-menu"><a class="item-a" href="home.php?p=link3">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Consegui por php, obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

Cara Tenta Passar Isso por ID e não por Classe
E Você está tirando e colocando a mesma função que está contida.

```
$('#item-menu').click(function (e)
{
    $('#item-menu').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Eu não posso repetir ID, quando são varias coisas com mesmo nome tem que ser com classe, se fosse por id cada item teria que ter o seu. Mas obrigada, consegui por php.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi por php, ficou assim:

```html
  <ul class="menu-main">
  <?php
   $link = strip_tags($_GET['p']);
  ?>
  <li class="item-menu <?php if ($link == 'link') echo 'active'; ?> " ><a class="item-a" href="home.php?p=link">Link</a></li>
  <li class="item-menu <?php if ($link == 'link1') echo 'active'; ?> " ><a class="item-a" href="home.php?p=link1">Link 1</a></li>
  </li>
 </ul>
```